# Expectation of a function of a uniform random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X$ be a uniform random variable with the pdf of $f_{X}(x) = \frac{1}{\alpha}, 0 \le x \le \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a real number. The goal is to find a closed-form expression of $\mathbb{E}_{X} \left[ e^{-\lambda X} \frac{(\lambda X)^{n_0}}{k!} \right]$, where $\lambda > 0$, $n_0 > 0$, and $k > 0$ are all constants.

**Some thoughts:**
I see the insider of the expected value form a Gamma pdf, which might be used to derive $\mathbb{E}_{X} \left[ e^{-\lambda X} \frac{(\lambda X)^{n_0}}{k!} \right]$.

Or, if it is possible to assume that $e^{-\lambda X}$ and $\frac{(\lambda X)^{n_0}}{k!}$ are independent, I would have proceeded to splitting the expectation into $\mathbb{E}_{X} \left[ e^{-\lambda X} \frac{(\lambda X)^{n_0}}{k!} \right] = \mathbb{E}_{X} \left[ e^{-\lambda X} \right] \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{(\lambda X)^{n_0}}{k!} \right]$.

However, I am unsure either of these is violating any mathematical generality.

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbb{E}_X\left[e^{-\lambda X} \frac{(\lambda X)^{n_0}}{k!}\right] = \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_0^\alpha  e^{-\lambda x}\frac{(\lambda x)^n_0}{k!} \ \text{d}x$$ with the substitution $u = \lambda x$ gives $$ \mathbb{E}_X\left[e^{-\lambda X} \frac{(\lambda X)^{n_0}}{k!}\right] = \frac{1}{\alpha \lambda k!}\int_0^{\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}}e^{-u}u^{n_0} \ \text{d}u $$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

[link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(-l*x)+*+x%5En+dx)

Following from the first line of your suggestion on WolframAlpha yielded one with a negative sign and an incomplete Gamma, which does not look right. Do you think I did right?

Comment: Well, the general anti-derivative of the second integrand is the incomplete gamma function. So, the antiderivative has no closed form in elementary terms. But, does have some known properties you can look into. But, as herb has mention, integrating by parts $n_0$ times either equation (though the second is likely easier) will give you the nice explicit finite sum given by herb in his answer. But, practically, make a $u$, $\text{d}v$ table and find the $j$-th term by pattern recognition. It's possible the finite sum can be further simplified, but I suspect it can't.

Comment: But, to be clear, yeah, I think you did do it, right, and WolframAlpha answers in terms of the incomplete gamma function because it's in its bank of special functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since both terms depend on $X$, they are not independent.  However for the given distribution, the expression you want is straightforward, even if a bit messy.

$A=E_X(e^{-\lambda X}\frac{(\lambda X)^n}{k!})=\frac{1}{\alpha k!}\int_0^\alpha e^{-\lambda x} (\lambda x)^ndx$

$A=\frac{1}{ak!}[\frac{n!}{\lambda}-\frac{e^{-a\lambda}}{\lambda}\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{n!}{(n-j)!}(a\lambda)^{n-j}]$

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

Would you be able to elaborate how you obtained the integral dx, from the first to the second line of your equation?

Comment: I looked it up iin a table of integrals.  However it can be worked out directly (tediously) by integrating by parts.  After each step the integral has the same form, but the exponent of $\lambda x$ is one lower, i.e. $n\to n-1 \to n-2....$ until you get to $0$.